# Filtering Invalid Byte Sequences for UTF8 Encoding in C# for a PostgreSQL Database

Tags: c#, postgresql, utf-8, odbc, npgsql

I have been searching and attempting  a lot of different solutions to this problem, but have not found an answer yet. Basically, I am inserting data from an ODBC connection into a PostgreSql database using the COPY query, but the COPY query stops and returns this error...

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x92
CONTEXT:  COPY [TableName], line 1: "189572|1-00-1202|1-|00-|1202||AP||1...
STATEMENT:  COPY [TableName] FROM STDIN (DELIMITER '|', NULL '')
```

The ODBC connection driver is set as ANSI and the Sybase/Advantage database it is pulling from is encoded as Unicode. To put this error message in perspective, out of 360,000 entries it only trips up on one of them. The issue is the COPY query stops and does not complete even if there is one error.

Below is my C# code that is extracting the data...

```
OdbcDataReader reader = test.ExecuteReader();
int rowCount = reader.FieldCount;

while (reader.Read())
{

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        dataEntry = dataEntry + reader[i].ToString() + "|";
    }

    dataEntry = dataEntry.Trim().Substring(0, dataEntry.Length - 1).Replace("\r",string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty);

    UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

    var raw = utf8.GetBytes(string.Concat(dataEntry,"\n"));

    copy.CopyStream.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
    dataEntry = "";
}
```

Basically, I am looking for a way to filter out invalid UTF8 byte sequences in C# and either remove them or replace them with a different character so the COPY query doesn't report an error. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/302sbf78.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/302sbf78.aspx). I suggest trying out different values of `throwOnInvalidBytes` and `encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x92` is Unicode [U+0092 private use 2](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/92/index.htm).

PostgreSQL supports this character:

```
regress=> SELECT E'\u0092', length(E'\u0092');
 ?column? | length 
----------+--------
 \u0092   |      1
(1 row)
```

so you shouldn't be getting an error. Run the above statement on your PostgreSQL instance and report the results.

However, it's likely that this is a symptom. Most likely the char is the second part of an escape sequence and your code is not doing correct decoding, so the first part gets consumed as some unrelated character instead of an escape, then you hit an error here.

This makes me wonder:

> The ODBC connection driver is set as ANSI and the Sybase/Advantage database it is pulling from is encoded as Unicode

... why aren't you using the Sybase driver in Unicode mode?

If you're using it in ANSI mode you must make sure that you (or the C# driver interface) correctly decodes the data sent by Sybase from the raw encoded strings sent.

I don't see a way to filter out bad data here because your C# app is what's producing the utf-8. It should be valid utf-8. If you're talking to an old/buggy version of Pg that can't cope with U+0092 for some reason, you could always filter that character out the same way you've been doing other substitutions, before you convert to utf-8.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For whatever reason the Sybase ODBC driver doesn't seem to have a UNICODE setting. I was able to use some break points and figured out that the string I was sending in had a double backslash "\\" which PostgreSQL didn't seem to like (probably because it is an escape sequence). So I replaced every double backslash with a quadruple backslash and it did not trip any errors.

Comment: Looks like your initial `copy` statement - which you didn't show - must not have `with (format csv)` then. But you're trying to supply csv like data not data for pg's native copy format.